# Add my own bounty to a question with bounty outstanding

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I've seen questions that have a bounty on them, but I'm interested in the answer as well, and I've wanted to augment with the bounty with some points of my own. Can we get a way to do this?

For example:

I see a question with a 100 point bounty on it, and I'm willing to throw 50 of my own points into the mix to make the bounty 150. I recognize that I won't get any control over the question/answer selection as a result, but it lets me do something more than just upvote a question if I want it answered.

Comment: +1. I like this idea.

Comment: Ah - I'm not sure how I didn't see that duplicate when I searched. I've answered there instead - thanks!